# powershell contains not working

Tags: powershell, if-statement, filtering, contains

I am trying filter by the name of each share using `$Share.Name`. However, when I try to use `-contains` in the `if` statement below, I get no results.

The result I want should be
`ADMIN$ - C:\ADMIN$`

I am working my way to being able to have a variable like:
`$ExcludeShares = "ADMIN$"` and filtering based on if the `$String.Name` is in `$ExcludeShares`

I am open to ideas on other ways to filter this.

Thanks in advance!

```
function GetAllUsedShares{
    [psobject]$Shares = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_share
    Foreach($Share in $Shares){
        $name = [string]$Share.Name
        if ($name -contains 'admin'){
            Write-Host $Share.Name - $Share.Path
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: `-contains` is for collection membership. You can use `-like` or `-match` for this sort of test though.

Comment: @EtanReisner `-match` worked, Thanks!!

Answer (score 25):

Contains is meant to work against arrays. Consider the following examples

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> 1,2,3 -contains 1
True

PS C:\Users\Cameron> "123" -contains 1
False

PS C:\Users\Cameron> "123" -contains 123
True
```

If you are looking to see if a *string* contains a text pattern then you have a few options. The first 2 would be `-match` operator or the `.Contains()` string method

1. `-match` would be one of the simpler examples to use in and If statement. *Note:* `-Match` supports .Net regular expressions so be sure you don't put in any special characters as you might not get the results you expect.

   ```
   PS C:\Users\Cameron> "Matt" -match "m"
   True

   PS C:\Users\Cameron> "Matt" -match "."
   True
   ```

   `-match` is not case sensitive by default so the first example above returns True. The second example is looking to match *any* character which is what `.` represents in regex which is why it returns True as well.
2. `.Contains()`: `-match` is great but for simple strings you can ....

   ```
   "123".Contains("2")
   True

   "123".Contains(".")
   False
   ```

   Note that `.Contains()` is case sensitive

   ```
   "asdf".Contains('F')
   False

   "asdf".Contains('f')
   True
   ```

Comment: Bizarrely .contains() works like -contains on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_share | where -Property Name -like "*admin*" | % { "$($_.Name) - $($_.Path)" }
```

Don't forget the asterisks in the where statement. It looks for exact values in that case.

If you want to write it out, this does the same thing:

```
$shares = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_share

# I pipe the $shares collection into the where-object command to filter on "admin"
$adminshares = $shares | where -property Name -like "*admin*"

# now we can loop with a foreach, which has the "%" operator as it's shorthand in the oneliner
foreach ($share in $adminshares) 
{
    # variables in strings are a bit weird in powershell, but you have to wrap them like this
    write-host "$($share.Name) - $($share.Path)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing `$name` for exactly 'admin' you can use the `-eq` comparator. This checks if the contents of $name equal the contents of your specified string 'admin'

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, .contains() acts like -contains on arrays:

```
$a = 'one','two','three'
$a.contains('one')
True

$a.contains('o')
False

$a.contains

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool IList.Contains(System.Object value)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case Insensitive Usage**

```
'WINLOGON','Something' -contains 'WinLogon'
True

'WINLOGON','Something' -contains 'WINLOGON'
True

'winlogon' -in 'WINLOGON','Something'
True
```

**Case Sensitive Usage**

```
'WINLOGON','Something' -ccontains 'WinLogon'
False

'WINLOGON','Something' -ccontains 'WINLOGON'
True

'winlogon' -in 'WINLOGON','Something'
True

$Array.Contains('WINLOGON')
```

**Case-Insensitive - All Uppercase**

Not needed but can make things all uppercase for comparison purposes.

```
$All = Get-Process -ComputerName $Target | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Select-Object -Unique
$check = @('winLogon', 'Something') 

# not needed but maybe for testing etc. 
$All = $All.ToUpper() # e.g. WINLOGON, W3WP, etc
$Check = $Check.ToUpper() #.e.g. WINLOGON, SOMETHING

If ($All -Contains $Check[0]) { ...
```